# Excel - How to count matches in data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am looking for patterns in the user journey of converted customers. I have each customers details in a row and then each step of the journey in it's own cell in columns, with up to 12 steps for each customer.

For example if I want to find the count of every customer who at any point in their journey has for example, downloaded a pdf and contacted us via email, what formula is best suited to this? I've tried countifs but couldn't get it to work over multiple columns.

Thank you.

Edit:

Thanks for the info so far guys, I'm going to try out some of what you've mentioned, but I've just made this quick example to show you what I mean:

[image]

In the example above everyone would have converted (purchased a product) after each activity step. What I've been asked to do is find patterns in activites that make people convert (i.e. when people download a brochure and make a phone call, in any order, they go on to make a purchase).

I work in web analytics / PPC but this info comes from the CRM and I've not done it like this before, and I'm probably not as versed in Excel as I should be for different tasks like this, but hopefully I'll get there! I'll go over whats been said already but anything extra is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried, and add some screens. You can edit your question so every one can see it by [clicking here](http://superuser.com/posts/767335/edit)

Comment: This is best done in a relational database model. Excel will be hard pressed to do this easily unless you setup a macro with dropdowns of each possible step. Give it a shot and then let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: You also make it sound like this comes from analytics software. Is there no feature in this to help? Funnels or goals would help with this in Google Analytics for example.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the replies so far, I've added a bit more info and a image if that helps. Unfortunately Gary this comes from the CRM team and it's just raw data, I work in web analytics so I know how i'd do it that way, and thanks Raystafarian, I will look into database models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Power Pivot Excel Add-In.  I would add the two tables of data to the Excel Data Model as separate tables, and relate them by Customer.  Then I would add Calculated Columns using the CALCULATE function - this accepts multiple FILTER sub-functions which should handle your requirements, e.g.

http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2009/12/powerpivot-dax-calculate-is-a-supercharged-sumif/

Comment: Hi Mike, I think this might be the way but I've not used Power Pivot or Data Models before, if you have time could you explain how to do that bit and I think I should hopefully be good from there. Thanks.

Comment: The other articles on that site are probably the best starting point for someone with an Excel background. Try starting here: http://www.powerpivotpro.com/new-to-the-site/